# Stack class in java.util a violation of Liskov substitution principle?

Tags: java

From the documentation of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

```
public class Stack<E> extends Vector<E>
```

Isn't this a violation of the Liskov substitution principle? The LSP in simple terms states that objects of the same superclass should be able to be swapped with each other without breaking anything.

For example: Let us say that I have a function that takes a Vector as an input. If while calling a function I start passing it a Stack then it might break because Stack prevents random access of elements.

```
import java.util.*;

class Book {}

class TextBook extends Book {}

public class Sample {
    public static void process(Vector<Book> books) {
        # This should not be allowed for Stack, Stack is FILO
        System.out.println(books.get(1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Book> books = new Vector<>();
        books.add(new Book());
        books.add(new Book());
        books.add(new Book());
        process(books);
        System.out.println("ok");

        Stack<Book> bookz = new Stack();
        bookz.add(new Book());
        bookz.add(new Book());
        bookz.add(new Book());
        process(bookz);
        System.out.println("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. First: Why do you expect that this class must follow the "Liskov substitution principle"? The specification does not require this. Second: Why do you think that it does not follow the principle?

Comment: @Stefan I added more details in the question to make it more clear why it violated LSP.

Comment: @Stefan I am not sure why any class should not follow LSP. This is one of the SOLID principles.

Comment: The ```Stack``` class supports random access to the data, so it does not violate the rule. However it might be optimized for push() and pop() only. You will notice the same with ```ArrayList``` (optimized for random access) versus ```LinkedList``` (optimized for quick insertion and removal).

Comment: Stack from data structures definition says that it should follow First In Last Out. How can we say Stack class supporting random access to data is right?

Comment: You may take a look at the source code of the ```Stack``` class to find the answer how they did it.

Comment: I checked the code and it does allow random access. My point here is the implementation of Stack class violated LSP and the reason is nicely explained by @JohnKugelman in his answer to this question.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal the principle is not saying what you think it's saying. It says that if you use it **as the parent class**, it should behave **as the parent class**. It doesn't say anything about the contract of `Stack`, which is the **subclass**.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think I got it. From the perspective of Stack class design, this is still a violation of LSP. The class should not have inherited from Vector because the behavior of Stack is well defined.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a violation of a different principle (see answer by SDJ).

Comment: @RealSkeptic then can you give an example where LSP principle is violated. I guess for LSP to be violated the same inheritance flaw should happen ( flaw mentioned by SDJ).

Comment: Imagine a class `Square` that inherits from `Rectangle`. That doesn't violate the inheritance principle because a `Square` is mathematically a `Rectangle`. However, if `Rectangle` has a `setWidth` and `setHeight`, and you override them in `Square` such that both of them set both width and height (to make sure it's square), then methods that use the `Square` as a `Rectangle` will see its size changing unexpectedly. That's an LSP violation.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Got it. Thanks for this nice example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

A stack should only allow for pushing and popping, but because `Stack` extends `Vector` it's possible to call the full set of `Vector` methods. Items can be inserted and removed anywhere in the stack, not just at the top. Conceptually, one should only call `push()` and `pop()`, but that's not enforced at the language level due to the backwards inheritance relationship.

`Stack`'s **code** doesn't violate the LSP, but its **contract** does: "The Stack class represents a last-in-first-out (LIFO) stack of objects." The fact that it doesn't enforce its own contract doesn't mean that it adheres to the LSP. Documentation matters, too.

A better hierarchy would have a `Stack` interface with a concrete implementation that is backed by a `Vector` but does not provide access to the full set of `Vector` methods.

```
public interface Stack<E> {
    E push(E item);
    E pop();
}

public class VectorStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
    private Vector<E> backingVector = new Vector<>();

    ...
}

Stack<E> stack = new VectorStack<>();
```

`Stack` and `Vector` date back to the very first 1.0 version of Java. Java 1.2 introduced a much better set of collection classes in the form of the `Collection` and `List` interfaces and their various concrete implementations.

`Stack` and co. are effectively deprecated and should not be used in modern code. The `Stack` API documentation recommends using `Deque` instead:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class. For example:
>
> ```
> Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
> ```

Comment: The LSP states that anything that uses the `Stack` as a `Vector` should expect it to behave like a `Vector`. `Stack` doesn't change the behavior for classes that don't know about `Stack`. The same is true for `LinkedList` which implements `Deque`. Anything that uses it as a `LinkedList` will not see strange behavior when they insert an element in the middle.

Comment: It's a violation because a stack should have fewer operations than a vector, but because of the broken inheritance hierarchy one can perform non-stack operations on a `Stack`. It doesn't violate any Java language rules because they didn't disable the non-stack operations inherited from `Vector`, but it's poorly designed and is a violation of the LSP because you *shouldn't* use any of the non-stack methods.

Comment: That's not a violation of the LSP. It's a violation of the idea of inheritance (a stack is not a vector). The LSP merely says that if you use it as a vector, it should behave like a vector. It doesn't care what the subclass contract is.

Comment: It is, though. The name "stack" implies that elements are only pushed and popped from the top of the stack. The vector methods violate that implied contract. The broken hierarchy means Java can't enforce the contract. One can obey it voluntarily but there's no enforcement. `Stack` doesn't violate Java's rules about subclass substitutability, but that's only because `Stack` doesn't enforce its own class design. It doesn't violate the LSP in code, but it does in concept.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I sort of agree to John's way of thinking. It doesn't violate the LSP in code, but it does in concept.

Answer (score 4):

The JDK's implementation of `Stack` is strictly additive: it only adds a handful of methods to `Vector's` implementation without taking anything away. For this reason, it is always possible to assign (substitute) a `Stack` to a variable of type `Vector` without restricting what the client code can do. It is thus **not a violation** of the Liskov Substitution principle.

However, its design is **acknowledged to be flawed**, but according to a different principle: *Inheritance is appropriate only in circumstances where the subclass really is a subtype of the superclass.*. From *Effective Java*:

> There are a number of obvious violations of this principle in the Java platform libraries. For example, a stack is not a vector, so Stack should not extend Vector.

Answer (score 0):

Having `Stack extends Vector` implies that it inherits all of the `Vector`'s methods. This violates the principle. Why?

The Stack abstract data type is a LIFO (last in, first out), and it usually supports operations like: `pop`, `push`, `peek`, `top`, `isEmpty`, ...

Java's stack supports operations that are not "stack operations", that are inherited from the `Vector`'s class, like `insertElementAt`, `removeElementAt` and more.